# JApplet setting width and height based on window width and height in HTML from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, japplet

I'm new and this might be a simple fix.  I am currently getting the window height and width using javascript and want to set an applet's height and width using javascript variables.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<title>Applet</title>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.writeln('Window width = '+winW);
document.writeln('Window height = '+winH);
</script>
<applet code="applet.class" 
        archive="applet7.jar, collections-generic-4.01.jar, colt-1.2.0.jar, jung-api-2.0.1, neo4j-kernel-1.6.M01.jar, blueprints-core-1.1.jar, jung-visualization-2.0.1.jar, jung-algorithms-2.0.1.jar, jung-3d-2.0.1.jar, jung-jai-samples-2.0.1.jar, jung-3d-demos-2.0.1.jar, jung-samples-2.0.1.jar, jung-io-2.0.1.jar, jung-graph-impl-2.0.1.jar, jung-jai-2.0.1.jar, blueprints-graph-sail-1.1.jar, blueprints-dex-graph-1.1.jar, blueprints-neo4j-graph-1.1.jar, blueprints-graph-jung-1.1.jar, blueprints-neo4jbatch-graph-1.1.jar, blueprints-sail-graph-1.1.jar, blueprints-orient-graph-1.1.jar, collections-generic-4.01.jar, blueprints-rexster-graph-1.1.jar, jta.jar, lucene-core-3.1.0.jar, neo4j-lucene-index-1.6.M01.jar, neo4j-remote-graphdb-0.8-1.2.M06.jar"
        width="1300" height="700">

</applet>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the code: `width="1300" height="700"` to be: width=winW height=winH.  I want the variables values to be given to width and height in the `<applet>` tags.

Can some one tell me how to do this?

Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write the applet inside `document.writeln()` like this...

```
document.writeln('<applet code="Dummy.class" width="'+winW+'" height="'+winH+'">');
```

Comment: When `deployJava.js` exists, don't use some home-rolled script without good reason (especially not one that fails to close the applet element).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `deployJava.js` to write the applet element.  See [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) of using it for a fixed size applet..

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.5.0/demos/jfc/Java2D',
                      code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet.class',
                      archive:'Java2Demo.jar',
                      width:710, height:540} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

You would add that just before the close of the `head` section & change it to something like:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.5.0/demos/jfc/Java2D',
                      code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet.class',
                      archive:'Java2Demo.jar',
                      width:winW, height:winH} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

---

One *unsupported* way to get a full window applet is to specify width and height of `100%`.  If it works at all, it should adjust when the browser window is resized.

---

Perhaps this app. is best coded as a frame and launched from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Sizing a frame dynamically is much easier & more reliable than doing so for an applet.